# How to use paypal SDK?

Tags: php, paypal

I am using https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK But when I hit any api from samples project/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample. It give me failed status . Basically I need to process credit card on my site. I am using PHP 5.5.9

I have used direct download for installation .

Is there any solution to this . Please let me know . Thanks

Comment: The status would contain more information than just "failed". What call are you making? What data are you providing (without the credit card number you're using)? What errors are being returned? Are any other status values provided? Can your server see the PayPal API properly? Just saying "it gives a failed status" is like taking your car to a garage and saying "my car is broken but I'm not going to tell you what's happening, what I was doing at the time it broke, or what make and model of car I am using"

Comment: Actually there are two messages coming failed and timeout

Comment: I moved my code to my server from local server and given all the permissions to it directories and its working .Thanks